# Why questions about race do not belong to biology?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I wonder why my question about race was closed as off-topic

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5630/does-europeoid-race-exhibit-greather-sexual-dimorphism-than-both-negroid-and-mon

Answer (score 8):

I considered closing the question myself when I first saw it, but then decided to let the community decide first. I wouldn't have closed as off-topic, but the question is very problematic in some aspects:

- It is entirely based on your own, likely biased observations. You provide no source or supporting data for your observations.
- Making such statements about a specific race is potentially offensive
- The value of using race to biologically classify humans is dubious. While there are certainly different human populations with different genetic markup, race is a rather arbitrary classification and there are much better ways to handle population differences.

In summary, I think it is a very problematic question so I'm leaving it closed.

Comment: It seems to me that these points make a good answer to the question instead of a reason to close the question. I don't think discussion of human differences should be off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

My initial assessment is that it's a genetic question that doesn't use the standard terminology to describe these groups. For instance, there is no Europeoid  classification. If we were to compare for instance *Yoruba* genes to *Han Chinese* genes, that would be a different story.

On a second pass, most of the question is related to very specific phenotypes where it is very difficult to imagine how the genotype would possible result in those differences. For instance, how would we know that Europeoid men look worse than women and how would we be able to quantify such things?

Comment: There is such classification.